# Camera preview in GLSurface view is too slow

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera, glsurfaceview

I am developing a camera application ,I have used camera API ,and GLSurface view to add live filters .I have used GPU Image library.The problem is camera preview is too lagging .I have tested on many devices ,devices with jellybean (API 15) will works perfect but preview of devices with lollipop and Marshmallow is too slow.Can anyone help ?

```
https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage
```

Comment: Take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will help you get a useful answer.

Comment: ok.........................

Comment: Because you use opengl in java, for faster rendering, OpenGL should be called in the NDK side.

Comment: I am not familiar with open gl and NDK ,i have just tried GPU library to fullfill my requirement ,can you help ?can you give any example links ....Thank you

Comment: @SungWoo The Java OpenGL ES wrappers don't add much overhead. There's really no advantage to using the NDK for something this simple (splat a single textured quad). It has zero impact on the *rendering*; any improvement would be on the call setup time.

Comment: @jaxon How does the Grafika filter demo look on those devices? (https://github.com/google/grafika, "show + capture camera" Activity.)

Comment: @faden : yes ,It's working fine